# htaccess rewrite rule only working with number wildcards

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wildcard

My htaccess rewrite rule is working as desired if I use digits in the wildcard, but if I use letters, I get a 404. I am attempting to rewrite the URL, not redirect.

It seems like I should be able to replace `([0-9]+)` with `([a-z]+)` to get letters to work, or replace with `([.*]+)` to get anything to work, however - I get 404's when I try anything to expect `([0-9]+)`.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php 
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/?$ mydirectory/index.php?param=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

I feel like I should be able to replace this line:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/?$ mydirectory/index.php?param=$1 [NC]
```

with this line:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ mydirectory/index.php?param=$1 [NC]
```

However, this doesn't work.

The desired URL is `http://mydomainname.com/mydirectory/myparameter/`

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is there any error message given? And why should that line match a URL that contains a slash (between `mydirectory` and `myparameter`?

Comment: Hi Nico, Thanks for your response - I should have been more clear. When I use digits it takes me to the index.php pages I have specified. When I use alpha, I get a 404 error.